# Bootstrap keep menu open on outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've exhausted most of the options I found here on Stack...   I've created a full width (horizontal) dropdown menu using Bootstrap 3. The nav contains multiple dropdowns within itself and they are activated (displayed) by the mouseenter event:

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
        if(!$('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) { // disable for mobile view
            if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) { // Keeps it open when hover it again
                $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
```

I've tried disabling the "outside" click by using:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    return false;
});
```

which works, however, it also disables the "mouseenter" event.... How can I resolve this issue? Any feedback would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you meant like this? http://codepen.io/saeedsalam/full/ZpgzQv/

i have added following code in addition with yours -

```
$(document).on('click','.dropdown.open a', function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Very close my friend. Basically, I need the dropdown to stay open until another one is activated, and disable the click...  I hope I make sense!

Comment: anyway, here is what you asked - http://codepen.io/saeedsalam/pen/ameoXr

Comment: BINGO! Great job, Saeed!!!  I should of been more clear... at least one submenu will be visible at all times...  it's displayed as fullwidth, so think of it as a nav below the main nav....  again, thank you!

Comment: glad to be helpful, happy coding :D